# MongoDB $or query not working for me after mongorestore

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I ran a **mongodump** and then **mongorestore** to move a MongoDB database from one computer to another. The data are there, I can query them (first query) and get results but using **$or** in a query produces no results (second query).

```
db.employees.find( { 'name.first' : 'Joe' })
-- vs --
db.employees.find( { $or : [ { 'name.first' : 'Joe' }]})
```

As far as I can tell, indexes have been recreated from system.indexes.bson, any ideas what is wrong?

indexes:

```
> db.employees.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "data.demployees",
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        }
    }
]
```

- original server: MongoDB 1.6.5 64b
- new server: MongoDB 1.4.4 32b

I was running the query through the console, not pymongo.

Comment: Are you getting an error back, or just no results? What results do you get from the first query? Does either query work in the mongo shell? Using the same pymongo and mongodb versions?

Comment: If you run the second query on your original mongodumped database, do you get any results?

Comment: Yes, running the 1st query gives me results, running the second one gives me no results and no error messages.

Comment: @Chris yes, I get results when running the second query on the original database

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you running on each?  The same?

Comment: @Hightechrider original: 1.6.5 64b new: 1.4.4 32b ... that is bad right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To really help here, we need a few pieces of information:

- version numbers (MongoDB and pymongo, server and new computer)
- output from `db.employees.getIndexes()`
- can you run a test on a smaller data set? (see below)
- can you double-check data types?

**Smaller Data Set**

Try copying out a small set of the `employees` to a new collection and run the same queries:

```
db.employees.find().limit(100).forEach( function(x) { db.employees_test.insert(x); } )
```

Basically, let's try to rule out corruption of data. Then let's try to isolate the version and see if this is a known bug.

**Double-check Data Types**

Ensure that the data types are correct.

**Is this a bug?**

This could be a bug, but if it is, the bug should be trivial to reproduce. Once you've double-checked that the system is behaving incorrectly, it's time to repro this so that you can at least file a bug.

Comment: have edited the question with indexes output and version of MongoDB that are different (that is probably the problem right?)

Comment: smaller data set, still nothing; data types are string, have tried using ObjectId as well

Comment: it was the version... have upgraded to the latest one from 10gen.. embarrassed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

pymongo requires quotes around the special operators--  have you tried this?

```
db.employees.find( { '$or' : [ { 'name.first' : 'Joe' }]})
```